# svg can't call Inkscape from LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, svg, shell-escape

The following MWE fails with LuaLaTeX but runs fine with pdfLaTeX on an up to date MiKTeX installation. Both cases work on a different machine with a TeX Live installation. Any idea what the problem could be?

(Inkscape is set up properly and `--shell-escape` is used.)

---

MWE:

```latex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{testdrawing.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="84.888mm" height="61.339mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 84.888 61.339" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g transform="translate(-58.204 -54.114)">
<ellipse cx="99.419" cy="91.239" rx="41.215" ry="19.192" fill="#e95d5d" stroke-miterlimit="120.01"/>
<path d="m107.6 54.114 14.212 16.051 21.28-2.6081-10.874 18.477 9.0564 19.433-20.933-4.632-15.683 14.618-2.0634-21.34-18.749-10.398 19.658-8.5567z" fill="#5d5fe9" stroke-miterlimit="120.01"/>
<text x="83.846474" y="83.715576" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="11.289px" stroke-width=".26458" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="83.846474" y="83.715576" stroke-width=".26458">Hello World!</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\includesvg{testdrawing}

\end{document}
```

---

Log file:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (MiKTeX 23.5) (format=lualatex 2023.6.20)  20 JUN 2023 12:10
 system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-16>
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-10-03.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload
/fontloader-2022-10-03.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'.

LaTeX Info: Writing file `./testdrawing.svg'.


\openout127 = testdrawing.svg

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local
/MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty
Package: svg 2020/11/26 v2.02k (include SVG pictures)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.s
ty
Package: scrbase 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.
sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-
hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.s
ty
Package: scrlogo 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcm
ds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr
.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks18
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces
.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics
.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.d
ef
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/04/15 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform
.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile
.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.s
ty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
))
\c@svg@param@lastpage=\count191
\svg@box=\box51
\c@svg@param@currpage=\count192
) (C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cf
g
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 227.

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.lt
x)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/transparent/transpare
nt.sty
Package: transparent 2022-10-27 v1.5 Transparency with color stacks

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/transparent/transpare
nt-nometadata.sty
Package: transparent-nometadata 2022-10-27 v1.5 Transparency via pdfTeX's color
 stack (HO)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
s.sty
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.
sty
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfut
il-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen142
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen143
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfut
il-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box52
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrc
s.code.tex
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.te
x)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfke
ys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks20
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks21

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfke
yslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks22
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count193
\c@pgf@countb=\count194
\c@pgf@countc=\count195
\c@pgf@countd=\count196
\t@pgf@toka=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks25
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count197

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
syssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count198
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count199
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-l
uatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count266
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
)
No file test.aux.

\openout1 = test.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
9.
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.
mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count267
\scratchdimen=\dimen154
\scratchbox=\box54
\nofMPsegments=\count268
\nofMParguments=\count269
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count270
\MPscratchDim=\dimen155
\MPnumerator=\count271
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count272
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
)
(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf
-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/epstopdf-sys
.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
)) ("|'inkscape' -V ")

Package svg Warning: No version of Inkscape was detected by invoking
(svg)                `inkscape -V'
(svg)                so the Inkscape export will fail quite sure as the
(svg)                command is probably unknown to your OS. You could set
(svg)                `inkscapeversion=<version>' manually but this is very
(svg)                unlikely to work on input line 19.

Package svg Info: Calling Inkscape on input line 23.
runsystem(inkscape "testdrawing.svg" -D --export-latex --export-filename="testdr
awing_svg-tex.pdf")...failed. 
runsystem(inkscape "testdrawing.svg" -D --export-latex \relax --without-gui --ex
port-pdf="testdrawing_svg-tex.pdf")...failed. 

! Package svg Error: Inkscape version not detected.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.23 \includesvg{testdrawing}
                           
It was tried to invoke `inkscape'
for file "testdrawing.svg"
but no result was produced. Check the log file
and set `inkscapeversion=<version>' manually.

runsystem(inkscape "testdrawing.svg" -D --export-latex --export-filename="testdr
awing_svg-tex.pdf")...failed. 

Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file
(svg)                `testdrawing.svg'
(svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the log file how
(svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took place and try to
(svg)                execute it yourself in the terminal on input line 23.


! Package svg Error: File `testdrawing_svg-tex.pdf' is missing.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.23 \includesvg{testdrawing}
                           
Did you run the export with Inkscape? There's no file
`./svg-inkscape/testdrawing_svg-tex.pdf'
although `testdrawing.svg' was found.


! Package svg Error: File `testdrawing_svg-tex.pdf_tex' is missing.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.23 \includesvg{testdrawing}
                           
Did you run the export with Inkscape? There's no file
`./svg-inkscape/testdrawing_svg-tex.pdf_tex'
although `testdrawing.svg' was found.

[1

{C:/Users/Fohmann/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-16>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 4416 strings out of 478032
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 413 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:32,3:3,4:10,5:23,6:2,7:58,9:26
 24783 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 94i,5n,88p,302b,124s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<//?/c:/users/fohmann/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmr
oman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 4091 bytes).

PDF statistics: 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: there were some issues in `|` input in the June Release. patch level 1 has gone to ctan... (not sure that is the issue here, but I suspect so, may look later)

Comment: it works fine for me and as far as I can see I have the same versions. Try it on a command line, and try first there `inkscape -V` and tell what it reports.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried that, same result: Works with `pdflatex`, doesn't work with `lualatex`.

Comment: I wrote only 1,5 lines of text and you still missed one question ;-(.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I indeed missed the prompt at the end there, sorry. Though the fact that it works with `pdflatex` (i.e. Inkscape can be called and outputs the appropriate files) makes it clear to me that Inkscape is not the issue. Inkscape reports `Inkscape 1.2.1 (9c6d41e410, 2022-07-14)`. (Exact same version is installed on the TeX Live machine.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried again after updating to patch level 1 with no change. I also tried re-installing MiKTeX, which didn't change a thing. In the end, I just removed MiKTeX and switched to TeX Live, which worked.